# jQuery validate() works on jsfiddle, but not on server?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm pretty new to using jQuery's validate(), so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

When I've pasted my form / validate function to jsfiddle, it validates correctly. Can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/AmLcV/6/ .

However on my live webpage, the form always submits no matter what. This is at http://students.cse.unt.edu/~haw0038/4890/index.php .

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="javascript:alert('form submitted')">
  <p>&bull; Which version would you like to run?<br/>
    <input id="variables" type="radio" name="version" value="variables" />
    <label for="variables">Individual Variables</label><br/>
    <input id="array" type="radio" name="version" value="array" />
    <label for="array">Array Representation</label>
  </p>
  <p>&bull; Would you like to find the largest, or smallest number?<br/>
    <input id="large" type="radio" name="type" value="large" />
    <label for="large">Largest</label><br/>
    <input id="small" type="radio" name="type" value="small" />
    <label for="small">Smallest</label>
  </p>
  <p>&bull; Use random numbers, or input your own?<br/>

    <input id="random" type="radio" name="numSelect" value="random" />
    <label for="random">Generate random numbers for me</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="nums" id="nums" value="How many? (2 to 10)" disabled="disabled"/><br/><br/>

    <input id="userDef" type="radio" name="numSelect" value="userDef"/>
    <label for="userDef">I want to use my own numbers</label><br/>
    <input id="userNums" type="text" name="userNums" disabled="disabled"/><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start the Simulation!" />
  </p> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

  $('#form1').validate({
      rules:{
      version: "required",
      type: "required",
      numSelect: "required",
      userNums: "required"
    }
  });
});
```

Any ideas why this would be happening? I have no idea what I'm missing here, or what would be causing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters you have an error showing up in the console at line 9 in `smallLarge.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have valdiate plugin included on your server please add this line and see.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

In JSFiddle this script is added this Script under manage Resources.

Its very good to use firebug for debuging javascript.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple like this, I thought it was a jQuery included library. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On jsfiddle there is the `jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0` plugin included.